# White spaces in file names not being recognized when 'exported' in Unix

Tags: bash, variables, unix, path

In MacOS I have created directories with names having white space. When use bash/Unix commands to navigate as shown below it works fine.

```
cd /Users/jdoe/"Box Sync"/Professional/"Classes Taken"
pwd
/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken

cd "/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken"
pwd
/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken
```

When I define the environment variables such as shown below the same path names don't work. Can anybody explain why it isn't

```
export CLASSES_TAKEN='"/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken"'
echo $CLASSES_TAKEN
"/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken"
$ cd $CLASSES_TAKEN
-bash: cd: "/Users/jdoe/Box: No such file or directory

export CLASSES_TAKEN=/Users/jdoe/"Box Sync"/Professional/"Classes Taken"
echo $CLASSES_TAKEN
/Users/jdoe/"Box Sync"/Professional/"Classes Taken"
cd $CLASSES_TAKEN
-bash: cd: /Users/jdoe/"Box: No such file or directory
```

However when I do this, it works:

```
export CLASSES_TAKEN="/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken"
cd "$CLASSES_TAKEN"
pwd
/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken
```

My question is how do I avoid having to use the quotes (`"$CLASSES_TAKEN"`) when using the environment variables. I want to be able to say `cd $CLASSES_TAKEN`

I checked many postings and did not find any answers to my problem.

Comment: You cannot, you need to quote if you want to keep the values. Otherwise, your `cd $CLASSES_TAKEN` will be translated into `cd /Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken`, so it will do `cd /Users/jdoe/Box`. However, maybe this works to you: `cd /Users/jdoe/Box\ Sync/Professional/Classes\ Taken`

Comment: Why fight it, if you like Unix/Linux features, eliminate a whole class of self-created problems from your everyday life and stop creating files/dirs names with spaces :-)! Isn't `BoxSync` as easy to read? (Granted, this doesn't solve the problem of Files/Dirs that you get from external sources). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**I strongly discourage this**, but you can make `cd` behave like `echo`, and just join multiple arguments with spaces:

```
cd() { builtin cd "$*"; }

export CLASSES_TAKEN='/Users/jdoe/Box Sync/Professional/Classes Taken'
echo $CLASSES_TAKEN
cd $CLASSES_TAKEN
```

This works as you describe, but has several pitfalls. The correct way is to quote your variables.